# Div table cells do not have the same width

Tags: html, css, cell

The widths are uneven for the table cells defined inside the table, I cant figure out why? Also apologies for the bad coding practice

Fiddle:[JsFiddle Link](http://jsfiddle.net/gr6v3tst/)

This the html. The table is desfined in the div class="mainstuff"

```
<body>
<div id="maincontainer">
    <div class="topbar">
        <div class="logo">
            Codeplayer
        </div>
        <div class="tabs">
            <ul>
                <li class="l">HTML</li>
                <li class="l1">CSS</li>
                <li class="l2">JS</li>
                <li class="l3">Result</li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <div class="run">
            <button id="but">Run</button>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="clear"></div>

    <div class="mainstuff">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="Html">HTML</div>
            <div class="CSS">CSS</div>
            <div class="JS">JS</div>
            <div class="Result">Result</div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

</body>

</html>
```

This is the related css.

```
  .topbar {
    background-color: #D0D5DB;
    width: 100%;
    height: 40px;
    border-bottom-width: thick;
}
body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
.logo {
    font-size: 1.8em;
    font-weight: bold;
    padding: 3px 2px;
    float: left;
}
.run {
    float: right;
    margin-top: -5px;
    padding: 6px 2px;
}
#but {
    padding-left: 15px;
    border-radius: 5px;
}
button {
}
ul {
    list-style: none;
    margin: 0;
}
.tabs {
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 240px;
    padding-top: 5px;
}
.l {
    float: left;
    border-color: #808080;
    border-style: solid;
    margin: 3px;
}
li:hover {
    background-color: #808081;
}
.clear {
    clear: both;
}
.mainstuff {
    display: table;
    width: 100%;
}
.Html {
    display: table-cell;
    height: 100vh;
    margin: 0;
    background-color: red;
}
.CSS {
    display: table-cell;
    height: 100vh;
    margin: 0;
    background-color: yellow;
}
.JS {
    display: table-cell;
    height: 100vh;
    margin: 0;
    background-color: blue;
}
.Result {
    display: table-cell;
    height: 100vh;
    margin: 0;
    width: auto;
    background-color: green;
}
.l1 {
    float: left;
    border-color: #808080;
    border-style: solid;
    margin: 3px;
}
.l2 {
    float: left;
    border-color: #808080;
    border-style: solid;
    margin: 3px;
}
.l3 {
    float: left;
    border-color: #808080;
    border-style: solid;
    margin: 3px;
}
.row {
    display: table-row;
}
```

Comment: So....why not use an actual table?

Comment: Was setting the widths manually before but that was tedious. Tired this short hand, just wanted to know what the problem is here

Comment: I'm not to used to using divs as table cells, but if they behave the same as acctual td's, then their width is relative to their content and, the content of other cells in the table, my suggestion is to use an actual table, and just define the width: .table > tr > td { width: 25% }

Comment: Why not use Zurb Foundation or Bootstrap templates....

Comment: Ok will try both suggestions. Though I removed the divs internal content, but the widths were unequal

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `table-layout:fixed` for your table.

```
.mainstuff {
display: table;
width: 100%;
table-layout:fixed;
}
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/sureshponnukalai/d1bvk79h/)